# how to use quotes in php code with html tags

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hi i want to use html code in php while command that generates html codes in every loop but i don't know how to use quotes in php code to send true values to java script!
this is my code in php

```
<?php
include 'Connect.php'; 
if(match($_POST['pId'], "/^[\d]+$/") ){
$pId = $_POST['pId'];
$result = mysql_query("select pName, pID, phName, phID, testHistoryDate, type, testAnswer from patient join reception using(pID) join physician using(phID) join testHistory using(rID) join test using(tID) where pID = $pId",$connection);
}
else
die("Insert true value");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row["pName"].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row["phName"].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row["testHistoryDate"].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row["type"].'</td>';
$type =  $row['type'];
$testHistoryDate = $row['testHistoryDate'];
?>
<td>
<span id='spryTanswer'>
<input type='text' name='tAnswer' id='tAnswer' value='<?php echo $row['testAnswer']; ?>' />
</span>
</td>
<td>
<input type='submit' value='Edit' name='edit' id='edit' onclick="sendToEdit('<?php echo $row['pID'] ?>','<?php echo $row['phID'] ?>', '<?php echo $row['testHistoryDate'] ?>', '<?php echo $row['type'] ?>')" />
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

java script code that get these values and send themes to another php code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendToEdit(pID,phID,thDate,type) 
{
testAnswer = $("#tAnswer").blur().val();
testAnswer = $("#tAnswer").change().val();
var info = 'pId='+pID+'&phId='+phID+'&testAnswer='+testAnswer+'&thDate='+thDate+'&type='+type;
$.ajax({
type:"GET",
url:"edit-testAnswer.php",
data:info,
success:function(){
}
});
return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you mean by "true quotes" or "true values", but rendering all that HTML in a PHP string like that doesn't make any sense in the first place:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <span id='spryTanswer'>
      <input type='text' name='tAnswer' id='tAnswer' value='<?php echo $row['testAnswer']; ?>' />
    </span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type='submit' value='Edit' name='edit' id='edit' onclick='<?php echo sendToEdit($row['pID'], $testHistoryDate, $type); ?>' />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: No this html codes generate in php while command so that i can't use your code!

Comment: @fireboy Yes this will render correctly even if it's within a PHP loop.

Comment: I copy and paste your code into my php code but server send this error! `syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\final\patient-tests.php on line 57` where your code starts!  php code ==> <?php your code ?>

Comment: @fireboy Well you can't put it in a PHP tag block… should be `<?php while(...) { ?> /* my code goes here */ <?php } ?>`. I think you need to go back and learn PHP properly, because it seems clear you don't have a firm understanding of some fundamentals of how PHP & HTML intertwine.

Comment: Ok i write this code before submitting my question to stackoverflow but in my code i get value of edit text to send this value to another php page to query on database and edit value of one field in database but when i use this code software can only get first edit text value and spry only work for first edit text! and confusing me!

Comment: @fireboy What do you mean "send this value to another PHP page"? If you're trying to call a PHP function in Javascript, that's just simply not possible.

Comment: No i send the value with $.ajax function of jquery!
I edited my question you can see what my code does!

Comment: @fireboy Except there's no jQuery in your code. This is all far beyond the scope of your original question, and I'm still not really sure what you're asking, or if you even know what that is.

Comment: I added my java script code in this code i only can edit the value of first text edit that generated with php in first loop `<input type='text' name='tAnswer' id='tAnswer' value='<?php echo $row['testAnswer']; ?>' />` but i can't get other edit text values when user edit value of that. i think my code error is in shen i select the edit text with jquery `testAnswer = $("#tAnswer").blur().val();` and only first edit text value get from this function. how can i get other edit text values with same id that user edit value of that?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd write the code you provided....

```
include 'Connect.php'; 
if(match($_POST['pId'], "/^[\d]+$/") )
{
  $pId = $_POST['pId'];
  $result = mysql_query("select pName, pID, phName, phID, testHistoryDate, type, testAnswer from patient join reception using(pID) join physician using(phID) join testHistory using(rID) join test using(tID) where pID = $pId",$connection);
}
else die("Insert true value");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
  <form onSubmit="return false;">
    <input type="hidden" name="pId" ="<?php echo $row['pID']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="phId" ="<?php echo $row['phID']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="thDate" ="<?php echo $row['testHistoryData']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="type" ="<?php echo $row['type']; ?>" />
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['pName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['phName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['testHistoryData']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
    <td>
      <span id='spryTanswer'>
      <input type='text' name='tAnswer' id='tAnswer' value='<?php echo $row['testAnswer']; ?>' />
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='button' value='Edit' name='edit' id='edit' onclick="sendToEdit(this.form)" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  </form>
```

function sendToEdit(thisForm) 
    {
      $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"edit-testAnswer.php",
        data: thisForm.serialize(),
        success:function(){
        }
        });
      return false;
    }

Comment: when i write this code i can't get the value of textField that generated and only i get  value of first textField!. in My code i sent value of edit text to another php page to query on database but i can't get values of editText except first edit text!!!

Comment: I edited my question i write this code before submit question to stackoverflow but i can't get values of edit text excepts first edit text!

Answer (score 0):

Put backslashes before the quotes, so `'<span onclick="alert(\'Do something\');">'`